# Testing for the occurrence of a substring in a string in Racket

Tags: string, substring, racket

Testing for the occurrence of a substring in a string in Racket.

My code is shown below.

```
(define (check-for-substring/list loc loc-to-find)
  (cond [(empty? loc-to-find) true]
        [(empty? loc) false]
        [(char=? (first loc) (first loc-to-find))
         (or (check-for-substring/list (rest loc) (rest loc-to-find))
             (check-for-substring/list (rest loc) loc-to-find))]
        [else (check-for-substring/list (rest loc) loc-to-find)]))

(define (check-for-substring string substring)
  (check-for-substring/list (string->list string) (string->list substring)))
```

Examples of tests are shown below.

```
(check-expect (check-for-substring "flag" "flagged") false)
(check-expect (check-for-substring "flagged" "flag") true)
(check-expect (check-for-substring "" "") true)
(check-expect (check-for-substring "a" "") true)
```

Examples of tests that do not work with my code:

```
(check-expect (check-for-substring "flaminegio" "flamingo") false)
(check-expect (check-for-substring "heiloght" "height") false)
```

Note: for those of you who are unfamiliar to the language of Beginning Student with List Abbreviations, there is no "local" function that allows functions to be defined within functions and "list" is used instead of "cons". Also, the "length" function outputs the length of a list, not of a string. You can ask for more clarifications in the comments.

Comment: @tjorchrt sorry. it's just that your code didn't work. There was a weird function "take".

Comment: I already metion #lang racket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "reset" the substring every time you *don't* find a match, otherwise you'll end up matching `""` against the full string, which of course will always return `true`.

An easy way to do this is by splitting the problem in two "loops", one that traverses the full string and the other that checks for a single occurrence of the substring, starting from the current position in the full string. Try this:

```
(define (check-for-substring string substring)
  (check-for-substring/list (string->list string) (string->list substring)))

(define (check-for-substring/list loc loc-to-find)
  (cond [(empty? loc-to-find) true]
        [(empty? loc) false]
        [(check-one loc loc-to-find) true]
        [else (check-for-substring/list (rest loc) loc-to-find)]))

(define (check-one loc loc-to-find)
  (cond [(empty? loc-to-find) true]
        [(empty? loc) false]
        [(not (char=? (first loc) (first loc-to-find))) false]
        [else (check-one (rest loc) (rest loc-to-find))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(check-for-substring "flag" "flagged")
=> #f

(check-for-substring "flagged" "flag")
=> #t

(check-for-substring "" "")
=> #t

(check-for-substring "a" "")
=> #t

(check-for-substring "flaminegio" "flamingo")
=> #f

(check-for-substring "heiloght" "height")
=> #f
```